# setting up XmlConfigurator Common Logging with log4net

Tags: c#, log4net, error-logging, xmlconfigurator

I have been looking at creating a common logging library for the company I work for, based on a [blog by Daniel Cazzulino](http://blogs.clariusconsulting.net/kzu/tracer-the-unified-dead-simple-api-for-all-logging-frameworks-in-existence/). so we can switch one out for another without to much disruption.

The first library I looked to use is `log4net`, but I cannot work out how or where you would setup a call to the `XmlConfigurator`.

I have tried adding an assembly on the project being logged, which kind of defeats the object of the exercise I feel, but that doesn't appear to work any way.

I have tried adding it as an assembly of the log4net Logging library, but that doesn't appear to work.

I have also tried calling `log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();` from the `TraceManager.Get` method, but all the log options (IsDebugEnabled, IsWarnEnabled, ...) are  disabled.

```
public partial class TracerManager : ITracerManager
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a tracer instance with the specified name.
    /// </summary>
    public ITracer Get(string name)
    {
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
        var logger = LogManager.GetLogger(name);
        return new Log4NetAdapter(logger);
    }
    /// The rest
}
```

Do I need to do something else?
Does the app config need to be in in the logging library?

**[Edit 1]**

Feel very silly....

I'd added `[assembly: XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]` to my Logging.Log4Net library, but I wasnt instantiating the TracerManager in my application on the tests I was performing... ID-10Tango issue

Comment: If you dissasemble http://nuget.org/packages/tracer.log4net you should be able to see how it's done

Comment: There isnt anything to disassemble? the nuget package adds a TracerManager.cs to the project.

Comment: The logging library certainly needs to be able to access the lognet config if it's going to do the configuration - would moving the config to it's own file make it easier? (Then you can use `log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new FileInfo(path_to_file));` which gives you the ability to change log levels etc at runtime)

Comment: I feel very silly........... I wasnt instantiating TracerManager >.<

Comment: In the end I added `[assembly: XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]` to my the Logger.Log4Net library and made sure I was instantiating TracerManager.... you can call me a div in the answer and I'll mark it as correct ;)

Comment: We've all been there, glad you got it fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd added `[assembly: XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]` to my `Logging.Log4Net` library, but I wasnt instantiating the TracerManager in my application on the tests I was performing...

ID-10Tango issue